# Example of how events cannot be independent and mutually exclusive at the same time?

Tags: probability

I understand how an event can't be both independent and mutually exclusive in terms of formulas.

Independent: $P(A \cap B) = P(A) * P(B)$

Mutually exclusive: $P(A \cap B) = 0 $

Therefore when A and B are positive probabilities they cannot be mutually exclusive.

I am struggling to understand the concept in terms of real life though. I've tried looking on the internet for a practical example in terms of cards or coin tosses and can't find anything. Is anyone able to give a practical example?

Comment: Think about it this way, if two events are mutually exclusive, then knowing that one happened tells you that the other didn't happen. This is the exact opposite of  the intuitive notion of independence, which is that knowing one event happens gives you no information on whether or not the other happened.

Comment: Draw a card from a deck. Consider three events "Ace", "Spade", "Heart". The first two are independent, the second and third are exclusive. Not at all alike!

Answer (score 0):

> I am struggling to understand the concept in terms of real life though.

We consider events to be independent when knowing whether one event happens *does not affect* our expectation that the other did happen.

We consider events to be mutually exclusive when knowing whether one event happens *makes us certain* that the other event cannot have happened.

Thusly, two events cannot be both independent and mutually exclusive (unless one is a zero measure event).

---

In the comments, @Ned gives the example of drawing one card from a standard deck.

The events of being an Ace and of being a Spade are independent; knowing that the card is an Ace will not affect our expectation that the card might be a Spade. (Thirteen of the fifty-two cards are Spades; versus One of the four Aces are Spades.)

The events of being a Spade and an Heart are not independent; knowing that the card is an Ace will surely affect our expectation that the card might be an Heart. (Thirteen of the fifty-two cards are Hearts; versus None of the thirteen Spades are Hearts.)   These events are mutually exclusive.